# how to select the option value in dynamic html table javascript. not getting updated option value from the database in the jsp page

Tags: javascript, html

element1 = document.createElement("select");

```
     var option1 = document.createElement("option");
     option1.value="warm";
     option1.innerHTML="warm";
     element1.appendChild(option1);

     var option2 = document.createElement("option");
     option2.value="hot";
     option2.innerHTML="hot";
     element1.appendChild(option2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the options `selected` property

```
 var element1 = document.createElement("select");

 var option1 = document.createElement("option");
 option1.value = "warm";
 option1.innerHTML = "warm";

 element1.appendChild(option1);

 var option2 = document.createElement("option");
 option2.value = "hot";
 option2.innerHTML = "hot";
 option2.selected = true; // LIKE THIS

 element1.appendChild(option2);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XdLBB/)

Comment: it's ok i have a three options in select tag, i selected one value. then it is stored in database. after how to get the selected option value out of three options  and show it in jsp page.

Comment: I guess you'd have to get the value from the database and set the appropriate option to selected ?

Comment: Hi Adeneo, Yes Exactly. how to iterate the option value out of three options. i am new javascript. Thanks in advance...